# Left kernel of directed Laplacian of a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-laplacian

Let $L$ be the out-degree Laplacian of a directed graph (with at least one vertex), in which there is a directed path from any vertex $i$ to any vertex $j$. In this case the kernel is one dimensional.

I have observed that the kernel is spanned by a vector with non-negative entries. Is this something known or straightforward to show? Are there any results for the left-kernel of directed Laplacians?

PS. Left-kernel is just the kernel of the transpose.

Comment: Yes, this is known. See Theorem 1 in [Siddhartha Sahi, *Harmonic vectors and matrix tree theorems*, arXiv:1309.4047v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4047v1), in which a vector generating this kernel is explicitly constructed. There is also a way to prove this implicitly, by showing that there is a nonzero vector in the kernel and then arguing that it cannot have entries of different signs.

Comment: @darijgrinberg that's exactly what I needed! Thanks. If you want, you could write an answer to I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer is an extended version of my comment, with more references.]

Let $V$ be the set of vertices of your digraph.
Let $A$ be the transpose adjacency matrix of $V$ (that is, the $V \times V$-matrix
whose $\left(i,j\right)$-entry is
the number of edges from $j$ to $i$).
Let $D$ be the diagonal $V \times V$-matrix whose $\left(i,i\right)$-th entry
is the outdegree of vertex $i$.
Depending on whom you ask, the Laplacian $L$ of the digraph is
either $D - A$ or $A - D$ or $\left(D - A\right)^T$ or $\left(A - D\right)^T$.
Of course, any statement about one of these four Laplacians can easily be translated
into a statement about the other three, so it does not matter which one we take to
be "the" Laplacian.
In the following, I shall define the Laplacian $L$ to be $A - D$.
It is easy to see that the row vector $e := \left(1\right)_{v \in V} \in \mathbb{Z}^V$
satisfies $eL = 0$.

Your claim is that if the digraph is strongly connected, then we can find
a column vector $v \in \mathbb{Z}^V$ that satisfies $Lv = 0$ and whose entries
are positive.

Here are three sources that prove this:

- [Siddhartha Sahi, *Harmonic vectors and matrix tree theorems*, arXiv:1309.4047v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4047v1).
  (Sahi defines the Laplacian $L$ to be $D - A$ rather than $A - D$,
  but this is of course insubstantial, since it's just a matter of replacing $D$ by $-D$.
  Also, instead of allowing multiple edges, Sahi puts weights on the edges of the digraph;
  this is a more general setting, to which you can easily reduce yours because you can replace
  $k$ parallel edges by a single edge with weight $k$.)
  Sahi defines a "harmonic vector" as a column vector $v \in \mathbb{Z}^V$ that satisfies $Lv = 0$;
  then he explicitly constructs a certain vector (called the "weight vector"),
  and proves that it is harmonic (in his Theorem 1).
  The entries of this weight vector count "$i$-trees" (= directed spanning trees with root $i$);
  it is easy to see that when the digraph is strongly connected, these entries are all positive integers
  (i.e., for each vertex $i$, there exists at least one $i$-tree).
  So this weight vector is a column vector $v \in \mathbb{Z}^V$ that satisfies $Lv = 0$ and whose entries
  are positive.
- [Arash Asadi, Spencer Backman, *Chip-Firing and Riemann-Roch Theory for Directed Graphs*, arXiv:1012.0287v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0287v2)
  .
  Lemma 3.1 here shows that if the digraph is strongly connected, then
  there exists a vector $R \in \mathbb{Z}^V$ such that $\overrightarrow{Q}^T R = 0$,
  where their matrix $\overrightarrow{Q}^T$ is easily seen to be our $D - A = -L$.
  Note that the proof of Lemma 3.1 in this paper omits explaining why there exists any nonzero vector $R\in
  \mathbb{Q}^V$ satisfying $\overrightarrow{Q}^{T}R=0$; but this is
  easy to see:
  We already know that the nonzero row vector $e$ satisfies $eL = 0$,
  and thus the matrix $L$ is singular;
  hence, there exists a nonzero vector $R\in
  \mathbb{Q}^V$ satisfying $LR = 0$.
  This vector $R$ thus must also satisfy $\overrightarrow{Q}^T R = 0$, since $\overrightarrow{Q}^T = -L$.
- [A. Björner and L. Lovasz, *Chip-firing games on directed graphs*, J. Algebraic Combin., **1**(4), 1992, pp. 305–328](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/JACO/Volume1_4/l31v67681vv718ll.fulltext.pdf).
  Proposition 4.1 (i) proves that the digraph has a strictly positive period vector -- which is defined to be a column vector $v \in \mathbb{Z}^V$ that satisfies $Lv = 0$ and whose entries
  are positive.
  The proof here is a bit of an overkill, due to the authors showing several things at once.