# Projection of the degree vector on the kernel of digraph Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-laplacian

Let $g$ be a strongly connected directed graph, $A$ its adjacency matrix, $d$ its in-degree vector, $D$ its in-degree diagonal matrix and $L=D-A$ its Laplacian.

According to this [excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312299/left-kernel-of-directed-laplacian-of-a-graph/3314143#3314143) the kernel of $L$ is $1$-dimensional and the vector $w=(w_i)$, where $w_i$ is the number of directed trees that originate from the vertex $i$, spans the kernel of $L$.

For some reason that would take too long to explain, I'm interested in the projection $\text{proj}_wd$ of $d$ onto $w$. It seems that it is always true that $\|\text{proj}_wd\|_1\le\|d\|_1$, where $\|\cdot\|_1$, the $1$-norm on $\mathbb R^n$. I know it's a stretch, but are there any such results?

PS. Clearly this does not hold for arbitrary vectors $d$ and $w$, in which case the inequality $\|\text{proj}_wd\|_1\le\sqrt n \|d\|_1$ is correct.

Comment: "It seems that it is always true that..." what evidence do you have of this?

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any bounds known for $w_i$ in terms of $d_i$?

Comment: @Leo I tried lots of examples, different types of random graphs and it always the bound holds. I don't know of any bounds for $w_i$ in terms of in-degrees.

Comment: @Leo a counter example would be very interested. I have failed to construct one